# how to send bson.M data in python

Tags: python-3.x, go, bson

i have an Api function in Golang that receive a json data and good working with postman
but i want te call api with python3 but error in parse body
this is my golang code:

```
var approve bson.M
err := c.BodyParser(&approve)
```

and this is my data in patch api :

```
{
    "result" : true
}
```

and this is my python script:

```
  jsondata = bson.BSON.encode({'result': True})
  options = CodecOptions(document_class=collections.OrderedDict)
  #decoded_doc = bson.BSON(jsondata).decode(codec_options=options)
  decoded_doc = bson.decode(jsondata, codec_options=options)
  r = requests.patch(approvurl,data=decoded_doc,headers={'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization':API_KEY,'Imei':'1234567890','phone':'123456789','email':'test@gmail.com'} )
```

and my backend in my golang throw this exeption :

```
expected { character for map value
```

and i compare json object in wirshark :
this is for postman:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FskTG.jpg)
and
this is for my python script
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jr4P.jpg)

please help me to solve my problem in python script

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that you're passing a Python dict using `requests.patch`'s `data` parameter, which expects a string. It looks like you want to send JSON, so you should use the `json` parameter (which adds the `application/json` Content-Type automatically).

Also, it looks like you're encoding a Python dict to BSON format, only to re-decode it back to a Python dict again. Unless I'm missing something, you shouldn't need to do that.

So your Python script can be changed to a single call to `requests.patch`:

```py
r = requests.patch(
    approvurl,
    json={'result': True},
    headers={'Authorization': API_KEY, ...},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by added a new function that check agent :

```
userAgent := string(c.Context().UserAgent())
        //print("userAgent=", userAgent)
        if strings.HasPrefix(userAgent, "python-requests") {
            eq := c.Body() //("result")
            if string(eq) == "result=True" {
                print("jsonBody is", string(eq))
                id, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(c.Params("id"))
                print("Approving started=", true)
```

tnx`